# Interpreting an answer given as two arrays

Tags: arrays, matlab, math, tree, minimum-spanning-tree

What does this means

> The edges of the minimum spanning
>    tree are returned in array mst (of size n-1 by 2)

?

When I run the program, at some point displays

[this two arrays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1gJx.png)

however I don't know how to interpret this as edges of the minimum spanning tree.

How do I take the edges? Is there a way to plot this answer?

Could someone help please?

This is the code.

```
function [mst, cost] = prim(A)
[n,n] = size(A);                           
A, n, pause,

if norm(A-A','fro') ~= 0 ,                 
  disp(' Error:  Adjacency matrix must be symmetric ') 
  return,
end;

intree = [1];  number_in_tree = 1;  
number_of_edges = 0;
notintree = [2:n]';  number_notin_tree= n-1;

in = intree(1:number_in_tree),                
out = notintree(1:number_notin_tree),
pause, 

while number_in_tree < n,
  mincost = Inf;                             
  for i=1:number_in_tree,               
    for j=1:number_notin_tree,
      ii = intree(i);  jj = 
      notintree(j);
      if A(ii,jj) < mincost, 
        mincost = A(ii,jj); jsave = j; 
        iisave = ii; jjsave = jj;   
      end;
    end;
  end;

  number_of_edges = number_of_edges +1;      
  mst(number_of_edges,1) = iisave;            
  mst(number_of_edges,2) = jjsave;
  costs(number_of_edges,1) = mincost;

  number_in_tree = number_in_tree + 1;        
  intree = [intree; jjsave];                  
  for j=jsave+1:number_notin_tree,            
    notintree(j-1) = notintree(j);
  end;
  number_notin_tree = number_notin_tree - 1;  

  in = intree(1:number_in_tree),              
  out = notintree(1:number_notin_tree), 
  pause,
end;

disp(' Edges in minimum spanning tree and their costs: ')
[mst  costs]                                 
cost = sum(costs)
```

Comment: That is not two arrays, it is one array (a matrix) with two columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An edge can be uniquely identified by the two vertices that it joins.
Each row of `mst` contains the two indices to the two vertices that span the edge.

The input graph is composed of a set of vertices and edges joining them, represented as an adjacency matrix `A`. If `A(i,j)` is true, then vertices i and j are adjacent (i.e. share an edge). In the output matrix `mst` this edge would be represented by `mst(index,:) = [i,j]`.

Comment: Oh ok, just to clarify the minimum spanning tree has edges connecting: 1-4, 1-5, 1-6, ... ?

Comment: @Isa: Indeed, 7 edges.

Comment: One more thing, I called the function with this: s=[1 1 2 2 2 3 3 4 4 4 5 5 6 7]; 
         t=[2 3 4 5 3 5 6 5 7 8 6 8 7 8]; 
         w=[3 5 4 7 4 9 8 3 11 8 3 9 8 7];
         G=graph(s,t,w);                  
         A=adjacency(G);                  
         prim(A)

Comment: Which is an example given in my class, so I have the answer to the exercise, but I have a different answer than the answer given by the code

Comment: Why is that ?--

Comment: Who knows? Maybe your `prim` is incorrect, maybe there is a typo in the input arrays, maybe your professor gave you a wrong answer. Many possible explanations.

Comment: oh ok, I am going to post it as a new question to make it clearer, hope you could help:)

Comment: @Isa: This is a small graph. Draw it on a piece of paper, draw the MST you got from your professor, and the one from your code, and see which one has a lower total weight. It is also possible they are both MSTs, a graph can have multiple solutions.

Comment: I did, but now I've just realize that the program did not returned the cost.. just returned `All zero sparse: 1-by-1` so I cannot really compare